# DRF - Render Model Serializer to HTML Create Form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-rest-framework

I am trying to render a form to create new objects. I have defined my API in a separate App and now I want to use it in another App of the same project. I followed the Tutorial and now I have a a Default Router, a ModelSerializer and a ModelViewSet and an automatically created browseable HTML API which also automatically renders a HTML form on the list page, to create new objects. I want to include this form now in my project. 
Of course I could write a form by myself and just use jQuery to make a POST request to the API but then I will have to create a form for every model manually. And if the model changes I will have to update the form. I was hoping to accomplish this using DRF and the documentation found here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

Sadly I have not found any example on the internet. I did find one Question on StackOverflow with the same problem but no solution.

**class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):** (in API/views.py)

```
serializer_class = TaskSerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.all().filter(owner=self.request.user.institute)

def list(self, request):
    serializer = TaskSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user.institute, created_by=self.request.user, modified_by=self.request.user)

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user.institute, modified_by=self.request.user)
```

**class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):** (in API/serializers.py)

```
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.name')
created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
modified_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='modified_by.username')
class Meta:
    model = Question
```

In **urls.py** I use the default router and add this:

```
router.register(r'questions', views.TaskViewSet, 'question')
```

Now, in my other App (same project), I want to have a create form, so I added this code to the template:

```
            <form action="{% url 'api:question-list' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/vertical' %}
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
```

Sadly I get an error now that does not help me at all when trying to access that website.

**'str' object has no attribute 'data'**

I have tried to add fields for **renderer_classes** to my ModelViewSet, but then my browse-able API breaks and is not useable anymore. I just want to include the form that is rendered at the bottom of the screenshot. Is this possible or do I really have to build it manually?

[image: 1]

Comment: I've got the same task and in my case I use `render_field` - `{% load rest_framework %} {% render_field serializer.name %}` If you change render_form to render_field, will it works for you?

Comment: I do not even render_field in the documentation... When I use it, I get the following error: _'render_field' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'style'_, so I added `style='rest_framework/vertical'` now the error is _'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'_ - I am going crazy. Maybe what I am trying to accomplished is not how the DRF is meant to be used

Comment: You have error message because there is no `serializer` variable in you template context. You need pass 'serializer': TaskSerializer() in your  Response.

Comment: I think I am closing in on the solution. I still have the same error but when I check the debug message I can now see in the local variables the fields from the serializer: `context_dict  

{'serializer': TaskSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    owner = ReadOnlyField(source='owner.name')
...` The only thing missing, is rendering this somehow. My view is only 3 lines long: `def manage_tasks(request):
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['serializer'] = TaskSerializer()
    return render(request, 'portal/manage_tasks.html', context_dict)`

Comment: IT WORKS! thanks so much. I changed the template to `render_form serializer` again and now it renders the form and when I hit submit it created an object in the database. Exactly what I needed. Though the action url is obviously wrong, as it points to the browsable API.

Comment: Happy for you! Cool

Comment: Good example. Will +1 if you post the working code as an answer.